# Scala Sub string combinations with delimiter

Tags: scala

My input string is

```
element1-element2-element3-element4a|element4b-element5-element6a|element6b
```

All the elements (sub strings) are separated by - and for some of the elements there will be alternatives separated by | (pipe).

A valid output string is which contains the elements separated by - (dash) only and any one of the alternative elements separated by |

All the List of valid possible combinations of output strings have to be returned.

Output:

```
element1-element2-element3-element4a-element5-element6a
element1-element2-element3-element4b-element5-element6a
element1-element2-element3-element4a-element5-element6b
element1-element2-element3-element4b-element5-element6b
```

This can be done using while loop and string functions but it takes more complexity.

(I'm a traditional Java programmer)

Can this be implemented using Scala features making it more efficient

Note: Input can contain any no of elements and pipes

Comment: Your example data are way larger than necessary to illustrate the problem you are facing. I can't even see your whole input without scrolling! Please consider revising them to look more like "A-B-C" so it's easier to understand what you want.

Comment: For the record, I'm voting to migrate this to StackOverflow, since you're asking for an implementation in Scala specifically, and any answers given in _other_ languages wouldn't really solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to fit the bill.

```
def getCombinations(input: String) = {
  val group = """(\w|\|)+""".r         // Match groups of letters and pipes
  val word = """\w+""".r               // Match groups of letters in between pipes

  val groups = group.findAllIn(input).map(word.findAllIn(_).toVector).toList

  // Use fold to construct a 'tree' of vectors, appending each possible entry in a
  // pipe-separated group to each previous prefix. We're using vectors because 
  // the append time is O(1) rather than O(n).
  val tree = groups match {
    case (x :: tail) => {
      val head = x.map(Vector(_)) // split each element in the head into its own node
      tail.foldLeft(head) { (acc, elems) => 
        for (elem <- elems; xs <- acc) yield (xs :+ elem) 
      }
    }
    case _ => Nil // Handle the case of 0 inputs
  }

  tree.map(_.mkString("-")) // Combine each of our trees back into a dash-separated string
}
```

I haven't tested this with extensive input, but the runtime complexity shouldn't be too bad. Introducing an 'Or' pipe causes the output to grow, by that's due the nature of the problem.